# CFBundleExectuable Error

Tags: iphone

Can’t install application

The application at /Users/myname/Documents/SDK/iPhoneApplications/x/build/Debug-iphoneos/x.app does not specify a CFBundleExecutable

I don't know what this means or how to fix it. Can anyone help?
It only occurs when trying to build to a device - it is an iPhone 3G running 4.1 and I am using the latest SDK which allows me to build on iOS 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This value is specified in your Info.plist file.  I would check your target for the debug configuration and make sure you have the correct plist file specified.

Double-click on your target and search for the Packaging section or for Info.plist.

If the plist is correct, check the content of your Info.plist to make sure you have either a value for either key CFBundleExecutable or key Executable file (they are the same value, but can be displayed with raw or friendly labels).

Comment: Thank you, the problem turned out to be there was no info.plist file inside the application, so I have copied one in form another project and edited it and it all works fine now, thank you for your help

Answer (score 9):

I also faced the same problem and the solution that worked in my case was to add CFBundleExecutable in info.plist.

Here are the steps to do it

1. Click on the + icon in your info.plist and add CFBundleExecutable as String type.

[image]

2.then in its value just add

```
$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
```

and then rebuild your app.

This worked for me and hope it works for you as well. All the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot! worked successfully !!! :D

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue yesterday and I spent more than 6 hours to find the solution, just follow the instruction below.

1- Go to your "TARGETS".

2- Then go to "Build Settings".

3- After that go to "Basic" then "Combined".

4- Then under the Packaging, you will find the "Info.plist File", check here if your file correct or not, if it's not equal to "Your project Name/Info.plist" you must change it to "Your Project Name/Info.plist".

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i have changed "Mach-O Type" to "Static Library", this may lead to the same question. just change it to Executable , worked for me

Answer (score 0):

After you setup `CFBundleExecutable` to `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)`, you have to set `EXECUTABLE_NAME`'s value in xcode. Select your target in `TARGETS` then go in the `Build Settings` tab and then search for `Product Name`.

Check that all your schemes product names are specified corretly to avoid any error (shouldn't contain any of the followin caracter `\ [ ] { } ( ) + *`).