# Expo Ios Build Does Not Contain Valid Info.plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, expo, info.plist

I have built a react native project with expo. Whenever I drag the finished .app file into my xcode window I get this error.
[image]

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Try to build for the simulator, and then drag the app. to the simulator and see if same error appear

Answer (score 0):

We will need more info about your app to really help with this. As you are using Expo, you have no direct access to the Info.plist file for iOS. That would have to be maneuvered using the app.json.
You would need a specific configuration property based on what exactly is believed to be requiring a "Valid Info.plist" the message says.

See Expo's documentation on this here: [app.json](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/)

Comment: I updated my question with more info. Do you think you can elaborate? (sorry i'm still a big noob when it comes to ios and expo)

Comment: I believe these links should help you: 
[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1273/_index.html). Note that what should be changed in your case is the CFBundleExecutable string type. Follow the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36793208/17180119)